# GNU `rename` - number pad multiple occurrences within the same file name

Tags: regex, rename, file-rename, batch-rename, backreference

### Advanced use of GNU utility `rename`

> TLDR:
> Number pad every number occurrence delimited by a `.`
> Example `11.2.7` to `11.02.07`

**Note: not incremental** - I wish to preserve existing numbers as they reference chapters

#### Here we have a list of files

```sh
1.1.4 Video - Anatomy of an IoT Attack-hspse3ffdx.mp4
11.1.11 Video - MAC Address Tables on Connected Switches-r4jd8ywqw8.mp4
11.1.2 Video - End devices-egvgnpczdg.mp4
11.1.8 Video - Static and Dynamic Routing-9hmp3pmjgs.mp4
11.2.1 Video - WLAN Operation-jgvaoufho4.mp4
12.1.6 Video - Three-Layer Network Design-pqo7z0dofi.mp4
12.2.1 Video - Security Devices-ba1rn27np7.mp4
12.3.1 Video - Security Services-doe61o7ndw.mp4
14.2.5 Video - Access and Social Engineering Attacks-ff2jvdisrh.mp4
14.3.1 Video - Denial of Service Attacks-0xc6nbzpnd.mp4
14.3.4 Video - Mirai Botnet-q22ur5mjby.mp4
14.6.2 Video - TCP Reliability - Sequence Numbers and Acknowledgments-12v657687z.mp4
16.2.3 Video - Amplification, Reflection, and Spoofing Attacks-gqc5r60t0x.mp4
21.2.8 Video - Cryptography-sd8nizpdl1.mp4
22.3.4 Video - Demonstration - Using a Sandbox to Launch Malware-4gfqq7cg6h.mp4
27.2.11 Video - Isolate Compromised Host Using 5-Tuple-41pcc9yx2j.mp4
27.2.13 Video - Interpret HTTP and DNS Data to Isolate Threat Actor-ke3dqr55hr.mp4
4.7.7 Video - Applications, Rootkits, and Piping Commands-7pptcz20yp.mp4
6.3.5 Video - Network, Host, and Broadcast Addresses-18zcrbwlfn.mp4
6.6.6 Video - Layer 2 and Layer 3 Addressing-k45ocxkbc5.mp4
7.2.1 Video - Network Testing and Verification with CLI Commands-asimubm3xa.mp4
8.2.2 Video - Sample IPv4 Headers in Wireshark-n29n6dgzc2.mp4
8.2.3 Video - ARP Operation - ARP Request-34um4wqbzd.mp4
8.2.4 Video - ARP Operation - ARP Reply-ghtdvvay1o.mp4
8.2.5 Video - ARP Role in Remote Communications-aaod3u3jsh.mp4
8.3.2 Video - ARP Spoofing-4drx7ijaex.mp4
8.3.5 Video - Sample IPv6 Headers in Wireshark-ibw3std2hh.mp4
9.2.5 Video - 3-Way Handshake-hsypao6yat.mp4
9.3.4 Video - TCP Reliability - Data Loss and Retransmission-ieh5e8m9k4.mp4
```

If we use `rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%02d",$&)/e' *.mp4` we only partially meet our goal as only the first number occurrence is padded:

```sh
01.1.4 Video - Anatomy of an IoT Attack-hspse3ffdx.mp4
04.7.7 Video - Applications, Rootkits, and Piping Commands-7pptcz20yp.mp4
06.3.5 Video - Network, Host, and Broadcast Addresses-18zcrbwlfn.mp4
06.6.6 Video - Layer 2 and Layer 3 Addressing-k45ocxkbc5.mp4
...etc
```

**I wish to have the first 3 number occurrences padded from x.x.x to xx.xx.xx**

The goal is have number padding as below:

```sh
01.01.04 Video - Anatomy of an IoT Attack-hspse3ffdx.mp4
... etc
```

Comment: Surely you don't want to zero-pad *every* number, or the first example would turn into `01.01.04 Video - Anatomy of an IoT Attack-hspse03ffdx.mp04` for example.

Comment: You are correct. I worded my question poorly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
rename -n 's/^([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})/sprintf("%02d.%02d.%02d",$1,$2,$3)/e' *.mp4
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)